# VBA Get Formula as text from a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new in VBA and I would like to copy the formulas contained in the "Input_wkst" in the "Output_Wkst" as text.

I am trying the following code in a double for-loop, in order to consider rows and columns:

```
myformula = "'" & Input_Wrst.Cells(i, j).Formula
Output_Wrst.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value = myformula
```

This code works fine, however it takes long time as it is processing cells-by-cells.

Is there a way to get the same result but using ranges of cells and therefore only one loop for rows?

For instance, is there something like

```
myformula = "'" & Input_Wrst.range(cells(i,1),cells(i,100)).Formula
```

Comment: Put `Application.Calculation.XlManual` at the beginning of your subroutine and `Application.Calculation.XlAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: In general it is slow to update a worksheet cell by cell. If you are updating an area with fixed data, it's much quicker to build a 2-D array and update the whole area at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Excel built-in function for what you want to do: `=FORMULATEXT()`. You can find information on this function all over the internet (including [this official URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8)).

Comment: And there is a buit-in `Show Formulas` button in the `Formula` ribbon, to quickly toggle between showing the formula and showing the result.